# SQLAlchemy: duplicate key violation because of old record that I delete in same session

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I currently have a User table (with some child tables). Upon doing a POST request, I'm trying to see if a user already exists, if so delete that user, and create a new User object/table (with the updated information).

This process looks like this:

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    stmt = delete(User).where(User.id == user_id)
    session.execute(stmt)
    session.commit()

    ...simplified but essentially...
    deserialized_user = User(user_id, ...)

    session.add(deserialized_user)
    session.commit()
```

Here, the user_id is the primary key and should obviously be unique.

However, I assumed that if I delete my User with <user_id> first, I should then be able to add it as it is no longer there. However this does not seem to be the case, as I get a duplicate key violation on the primary key of my User table.

How can I solve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: add a `session.flush()` after the first commit and see if that resolves it

Comment: You can DELETE and INSERT within a single transaction, without any unique key violations. Most likely you have two different transactions, where the first transaction hasn't been committed yet, and the second transaction tries to insert the new data.

Comment: @FrankHeikens this solved my issue, I just had to get rid of the first commit then everything works. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reproducible from the code in the question - perhaps the issue relates to tthe `deserialized_user`.